# Is it possible generate a hash of result set using django orm?

Tags: django, postgresql, hash, orm

I need something like this: [How to generate a hash of the result set in Postgress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533314/how-to-generate-a-hash-of-the-result-set-in-postgress)

Is it possible using django orm?

Does anyone have any reference?

Comment: You can create a custom DB function using the [***`Func` expression***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Django's User model it will be like below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Concat, Func, CharField

User.objects.annotate(
    hash=Func(
        Concat('first_name', 'last_name', output_field=CharField()),
        function='md5',
    )
)
```

Comment: I think I understand. But... How can I get the hash?

Comment: Let's say that we assigned it to a variable called result. Then it would be `result[0].hash` for the first item.